# Use of $near to find nearest polygons of a certain point in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have some polygons in a collection each as a document. I need to find the nearest polygons of a point in radius 50 KM. $near in mongo db will work for points. Is there any way to use $near to search nearest polygons of a certain point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$near` to do this out-of-the-box. `$near` finds the nearest geometries to a point. The geometries do not have to be points:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ 
    "loc" : { 
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[10.0, 0.0], [11.0, 0.0], [11.0, 1.0], [10.0, 1.0], [10.0, 0.0]]]
     } 
})
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "loc" : "2dsphere" })
> db.test.find({ 
    "loc" : {
        "$near" : { 
            "$geometry" : { 
                "type" : "Point", 
                "coordinates" : [8.5, 12.1] 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}, { "_id" : 0, "loc.type" : 1 })
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon" } }
```

Comment: I want to know the `distance` of point and polygon. Is it from point to the nearst point of polygon? What if point is in polygon ?

Comment: how can i do this in MongoDB and java?

Comment: Does this include points that are inside a polygon too, ie. i want polygons nearest to a point where the point is completely outside the polygon. Does it work like that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [$geoIntersects](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) instead of $near?